# How to use intel 2200BG on an HP Pavillion DV1000?

Tags: wireless, hardware, intel-wireless, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavillion DV1000 and I cannot use the wireless with any distro. I am a new user in linux and I need a guide to follow. Do you know something?

Comment: please provide more info

Comment: Give us output of `ifconfig -a` `lspci` and `lsmod`

Answer (score 0):

My Asus Laptop has an 2200BG build in. I had nothing to do to make it work.

Try loading the module

```
sudo modprobe ipw2200
```

but before, look whether this has already happened:

```
lsmod | grep ipw2200
```

dmesg is another diagnostic:

```
dmesg | grep 2200
[   17.054310] ipw2200: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200/2915 Network Driver, 1.2.2kmprq
[   17.054314] ipw2200: Copyright(c) 2003-2006 Intel Corporation
[   17.054403] ipw2200 0000:02:04.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 4 (level, low) -> IRQ 4
[   17.054480] ipw2200: Detected Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection
[   17.054521] ipw2200 0000:02:04.0: firmware: requesting ipw2200-bss.fw
[   17.662676] ipw2200: Detected geography ZZM (11 802.11bg channels, 0 802.11a channels)
```

and lspci, get the slot info:

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
02:04.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)
```

and then, for example:

```
lspci -vv -s 02:04.0
```

Comment: Dosnt work =(((

Comment: Did you at least find something out? Is the module loaded? You may put additional information in your question. With a similar chip, the ipw2100, I had issues with the IRQ being used by something else. Experimenting in the BIOS helped, and `dmesg | grep eth` helped finding it.